# How to work with C redirection in Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, io-redirection

I'd like to redirect the Standard Input in C so that I can get a number from a CSV file with `scanf` and display it in the console using `printf`. This is what my code looks like:

```
int main() {

    int number;

    printf("Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", & number);
    printf("The number is %d", number);

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to specify the location of the folder containing the CSV file and the CSV file for the redirection in advance with

```
> ./myProject < myCSV.csv
```

But straight after I run the program, the console looks like this:

> Number:

When I type the above code I suppose `scanf` eats `> ./myProject < myCSV.csv` up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `scanf("%d", number);` should be `scanf("%d", &number);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @BLUEPIXY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running your program from within Xcode then use `Product` => `Scheme` => `Edit Scheme...` (shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd><</kbd>) to set the command line arguments (including any I/O redirection). You can also set additional environment variables here, if needed.

Note that if you plan to specify relative paths as command line arguments then the working directory may need to be set appropriately - this option is found in the `Options` tab, to the right of the `Arguments` tab in the `Edit Scheme...` dialog.

---

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately it seems that a bug introduced in Xcode 4 is still present in at least Xcode 6.4, which means that I/O redirection specified using the above method currently does not work correctly (oddly it worked correctly in Xcode 3 and earlier).

To work around this I suggest specifying an optional input file name on the command line, and then explicitly handle this in your code, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int number;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        FILE * fp = freopen(argv[1], "r", stdin);
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            perror(argv[1]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    printf("Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("The number is %d\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't supply a command line argument then stdin will be read as normal, but if you do specify a file name then this will be used in place of stdin, e.g.

```
$ ./my_program                # reads from stdin
$ ./my_program numbers.csv    # reads from numbers.csv
```

As described above in the original answer (left for posterity, in case this bug gets fixed in Xcode 7 or later) you can set the command line argument in the `Edit Scheme...` dialog:

[image: Set command line argument]

As also noted above you should also set the working directory appropriately - I usually set it to `$(PROJECT_DIR)`, so that it's at the project root directory, but you can set it to anything you like:

[image: Set working directory]

Comment: Thanks! Here's what the scheme control panel looks like. Would you have set it up the same way? I appreciate your help.  http://i.imgur.com/o3Q2648.png

Comment: The arguments look OK, but you don't need to add `number` as an environment variable (I guess you're not familiar with general *nix concepts ?). Also make sure your working directory is correct if you're going to use relative paths (see the `Options` tab, next to the `Arguments` tab).

Comment: Thanks Paul! I can't seem to be able to get it working, probably because the location of the input file is wrong. Do you think I should put the CSV file inside the folder that contains the executable? (the Products folder). Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Actually your output redirection looks wrong - I would remove that for now and just output to the console. For the input redirection just set the custom working directory to wherever the .csv file is located and then make your command line arguments `< file.csv` (and nothing else).

Comment: The command line argument is now `< number.csv` and the working directory is pointing at the input file. However it's still not working (the console just prints out `Number:` and nothing else) and I don't really know what's wrong with the project. Thanks for your help, if you have any further tips they will be very welcome.

Comment: Is this a very old version of Xcode by any chance ? I remember there was a bug in Xcode 4 when doing I/O redirection like this - I would hope it's been fixed by now. What version are you using ?

Comment: That's definitely a good point. I'm using version 6.4 but I also ran the program on 7.0 beta.

Comment: I don't have access to a Mac right now, but I'll check this with Xcode 6.4 tomorrow if I get a chance to confirm that the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate you helping me though this question! I uploaded a copy of the project so that you can replicate the same environment. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fy4r9zex2syahen/QuestionStack.zip?dl=0

Comment: Sorry - it looks like the bug introduced in Xcode 4 is still present in Xcode 6.4 - I've added an update to the answer above describing a workaround for this.

Comment: Thanks! This works beautifully. Is there any way I can specify an output file? Perhaps we'll need to add some code and add a new argument to the scheme.

Comment: Sure - just use the same technique for `stdout` and use a second command line argument, `argv[2]`.

Comment: Thanks again Paul! Here's what part of the code looks so far: http://i.imgur.com/m93SML4.png. I tweaked it a little bit. Here's what the arguments list looks like: http://i.imgur.com/bs8usuV.png. It doesn't seem to be working though. What am I doing the wrong way? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It should be"w" for the output file (it needs to be writeable). You also need to check for argc > 2, not 1, if you are expecting a second argument. Suggest you read a few man pages for the C std library functions to get a little more familiar with this stuff.

Comment: We're now at Xcode version 10.0.0 and the bug is still present, but I'm sure the Xcode developers are burning the midnight oil to get this issue fixed ASAP :-)